# Qt Creator - How to convert .ui file to .py file on Mac?

Tags: macos, pyqt

How do I convert my `.ui` files generated by Qt Creator to `.py` files?

I used to convert the `.ui` files to `.py` files using a `.bat` file on Windows:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.ui) do (
    echo %%f    
    C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyuic5.bat -x %%f -o %%~nf.py
)
pause
```

I now no longer have access to a PC for the conversion (plus I'm tired of switching computers just to convert the file), so I need to be able to just convert the `.ui` files to `.py` in mac⁠OS.

Comment: Is there a `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyuic.sh` shell script? If so call it from a new sh script wrapper.

Comment: What are you asking? How to run ```pyuic5``` on Mac? How to do a loop? What research have you done, and what have you learned?

Comment: @Scott The question is about 2 years old and it was answered by someone who recommends just using `pyuic5` on macOS but — as a macOS user — I cannot even run it on my setup. So hey… Who knows at this point? Unless someone with macOS and experience with Qt can post here I guess.